# How Connect my wpf app to database online?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I developed a WPF Application for an intranet connection, connecting to a database (SQL Server) in a local server, but now my company bought a new server in abroad and so they wish to connect this application to that server.

I should create a connection between this application to a database Online (SQL Server), so I ask you which is the best way to make a connection that allows the users here to manipulate the data like in past time?

If you have a better advice let me know I will appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Connecting to a SQL server in a remote location is not much different to connecting to one locally, you just have to specify the appropriate host name or ip in the connection string.

However there does have to be some kind of route to the remote server, which usually requires setting up a VPN if you need to go out over the internet but that's not really a programming question.

Comment: ,thanks for your reply ,now we have a server where users connect to Database Sql Server in our company but within 2 weeks we should move this SqlServer on another Server in abroad(Germany) and continue to use this apps becuase there are others our office in abroad that should begin to use it ,hope i was clear with my question,anyway if i understand well i should just change the Ip or hostname in the connection string of my app? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes that's correct just change the hostname or ip in the connection string, so long as all clients can connect to that ip on the port that SQL server is using you should be good to go.

Comment: ,Thanks so much Ben now i try and i let you know the result .

Comment: Rather depends on whether the SQL Server is exposed to the internet (they quite often are) - that said one would hope that the server is on something other than the default port (1433) and so that - the port number - may also need to be reflected in the connection string

Comment: @Murph It doesn't so much depend whether SQL Server is exposed to the internet as it does on whether there is a route to the sql server and that the port it is running on isn't blocked which i think i did point out.

Comment: Ben - my problem is with "usually requires setting up a VPN" - I'm not remotely convinced that that's a good generalisation - I think that "may, for example, require setting up a VPN" would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You need only to change the connection string.

Probably it would be better to wrap SQL Server by some kind of service, like WCF. It would be more secure and flexible. You could use WCF Data Services to make it really fast.